# ionic/angular validation_1.validateName is not a function [ERROR] Could not generate page

Tags: angular, ionic4

I use Ionic Angular.
Following an upgrade from angular 9 to angular 14 and from ionic 4 to ionic 5, I can no longer create pages or components with the command :

```
ionic g page [PATH]
```

a warning is raised :

> The 'path' option in
> '[ABSOLUTE_PATH]\node_modules@ionic\angular-toolkit\schematics\page\schema.json'
> is using deprecated behaviour. 'workingDirectory' smart default
> provider should be used instead.

And also an error that I think is the cause of the problem:

> validation_1.validateName is not a function
> [ERROR] Could not generate page.

How can I make it work again?

Here is my package.json :

```
{
  "name": "captarget-archery",
  "version": "0.0.5",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^14.2.5",
    "@angular/common": "^14.2.5",
    "@angular/core": "^14.2.5",
    "@angular/fire": "^7.4.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.2.5",
    "@angular/router": "^14.2.5",
    "@angular/service-worker": "^14.2.5",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/in-app-purchase-2": "^5.45.0",
    "@capacitor/android": "^3.2.0",
    "@capacitor/app": "^1.0.3",
    "@capacitor/core": "^3.6.0",
    "@capacitor/ios": "^3.6.0",
    "@capacitor/splash-screen": "^1.2.2",
    "@ionic-native/app-availability": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/camera": "^5.29.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-purchase-2": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^6.3.0",
    "@ionic/lab": "^3.2.7",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.2.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^14.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.36",
    "angular-animate": "^1.8.2",
    "angularfire2": "^5.4.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
    "chartjs-plugin-labels": "^1.1.0",
    "cocoapods": "0.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-appavailability": "^0.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "^5.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^5.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-purchase": "^10.6.1",
    "cordova-res": "^0.15.3",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "crypto-js": "^4.0.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "firebase-functions": "3.23.0",
    "googleapis": "^85.0.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "inquirer": "^9.1.3",
    "install": "0.13.0",
    "ionic": "^4.1.2",
    "ionic2-calendar": "^0.6.4",
    "jetifier": "^2.0.0",
    "ng-particles": "^2.17.0",
    "ng2-charts": "^2.3.0",
    "ngx-autosize": "^1.8.0",
    "npm": "8.19.1",
    "resources": "^0.4.3",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.7",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.7",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "util": "^0.12.4",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "^0.1402.5",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.2.5",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^14.2.5",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "^14.2.5",
    "@angular/cli": "14.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.2.5",
    "@angular/language-service": "^14.2.5",
    "@capacitor/cli": "^3.6.0",
    "@ionic-native/network": "^5.32.0",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^2.3.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^8.10.61",
    "capacitor": "^0.0.3",
    "capacitor-resources": "^1.2.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.2",
    "firebase": "^9.11.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^11.1.0",
    "http-server": "^14.1.1",
    "jasmine-core": "^4.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "4.6.4"
  },
  "browser": {
    "crypto": false
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution : npm i @ionic/angular-toolkit@latest --save-dev